# ruby each.with_index - reflect input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have looked around for info on how to do this, just can't quite get it myself. Fairly new to Ruby and I'm building a gem. I can return a list of results from a website ok with Nokogiri.

The issue I'm having is how to take an input number and relate it to another piece of text from the website I'm scraping. So you pick a movie title by number from a list and then you return the relevant movie outline. Maybe I don't want to iterate through all the objects (again) at all.

This is what I'm looking at:

```
def menu
  input = nil
  while input != "exit"
    input = gets.strip.downcase
    if input.to_i < 24
      @movies.each.with_index(1) do |movie, i|
        puts "Description: #{movie.outline}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So we create a variable for input. While the input is not the word exit and less than the number 24, we iterate through the movies and put the relevant one by index number. Currently putting ALL the movie outlines so I feel like I should ditch the iteration. I've tried a number of things around adding the input to movie.outline...

Any help or hints would be great!

Comment: can you provide a sample desired output?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure, but, are you maybe just trying to do this?

```
input = gets.to_i
if input < 24
   movie = @movies[input]
   puts "Description: #{movie.outline}"
end
```

Or something to that effect?

If you want to access an Array element, you use the `[]` notation (I'm assuming `@movies` is an Array, but if it's some other enumerable, you'll need to tell us what that is).